# Which ports needs to be open on an Acumos (oneclick) installations

Tags: acumos

I am setting up an Acumos installation and want to configure my firewall to allow external users to access the Acumos platform after the install is completed. I am using the oneclick.sh install script (oneclick.sh docker) to do the installation.

When using the Acumos oneclick.sh install script it is possible to set values for a lot of different ports in the acumos-env.sh file. Some of the ports are probably for internal use (for intra communication between Acumos platform elements). I would like to know which ports actually needs to be open for external users to **use** the platform. Is it only the ACUMOS_KONG_PROXY_SSL_PORT (default 30443) or does other ports have to be open as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular users need access to two Acumos endpoints: the Portal-Marketplace web site and the On-Boarding server.  With that said, both endpoints should be proxied by Kong to secure the traffic, so I think you're on the right path with opening only port 30443. Have you done this already, but hit problems?

Comment: I have not experienced problems yet, I was just wondering. I have now finished the installation and so far it looks like that it works as it should (with only the Kong proxy port open in the firewall).

Comment: Glad to hear it. If this answer is sufficient, please click the check mark to accept it, thx.